# How to download files from telegram to Gdrive using Google App Script by bot API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, telegram-bot

Noob question, I am trying to download files from Telegram servers to Google Drive using Bot Api and Google App Script. As far as I know there is a bot called @getpubliclink in Telegram, which downloads the files to their servers and again re-upload them to Google Drive and it creates bandwidth problem and not a server-less one.

So if this concepts works, then those issues will be solved.

This is my code in Google App Script:

```js
var token = "token"; // FILL IN YOUR OWN TOKEN
var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token;
var webAppUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/"; // FILL IN YOUR GOOGLE WEB APP ADDRESS
//var folder = "1-n9vtrED_oUOKrTnHlEeZR0B2uK8it9O"; // FILL IN THE ID OF YOUR SPREADSHEET
var downloadUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/file/bot" + token;



function getMe() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/getMe";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function getUpdates(){
  var url = telegramUrl + "/getUpdates";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  
}

function setWebhook() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function getFile(file_id) {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/getFile?file_id=A...EC";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
   Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function File(file_id,file_path) {
  var FileURL = downloadUrl + "/photos/f.jpg";
 // var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}







function downloadFile(fileURL,folder) {
  
  var fileName = "";
  var fileSize = "file_size";
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  var rc = response.getResponseCode();
  
  if (rc == 200) {
    var fileBlob = response.getBlob()
    var folder = DocsList.getFolder(folder);
    if (folder != null) {
      var file = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
      fileName = file.getName();
      fileSize = file.getSize();
    }
  }

}
```

So far I got the file as text in response and I am using `fileURL` for Google Drive  but it needs the url, if a better solution is available. How can I download these files into a Google Drive?

Answer (score 0):

I used this script in my project to move the file in Telegram to Google Drive.
And it worked!

```
var fileid = contents.message.photo[contents.message.photo.length - 1]["file_id"];

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + '/getFile?file_id=' + fileid);

var urlphoto = 'https://api.telegram.org/file/bot' + token + '/' + JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).result["file_path"];

var resa = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlphoto);
var blob = resa.getBlob();

var jum = DriveApp.createFile(blob).setName(new Date().toLocaleString());
```